# How can I loop through to make a list with a Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The result I want is this

```
  <ul id="toc">
    <li><Link to="/page1">Page 1</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/page1">Page 2</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/page1">Page 3</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/page1">Page 4</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/page1">Page 5</Link></li>
  </ul>
```

its a lot so I want to loop through and make the links

```
const pages = [
  { name: "Page 1", url:"/page1"},
  { name: "Page 2", url:"/page2"},
  { name: "Page 3", url:"/page3"},
  { name: "Page 4", url:"/page4"}
]
```

now in my JSX

```
  <ul id="toc">
      {Object.keys(pages).map((name, url) => {
        <li><Link to="{url}">{name}</Link></li>
      })}

  </ul>
```

However I am not seeing anything, I am not seeing the loop? is this the way to do it in JSX

Sorry for the layman q I am still new to react/js

Comment: use this: `{pages.map((name, url) => <li><Link to={url}>{name}</Link></li>)}
`, pages is an array not an object so no need to use `Object.keys`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four little things that add up:

```
Object.keys(pages).map((name, url) => {
  <li><Link to="{url}">{name}</Link></li>
})
```

1. Since `pages` is already an array, `Object.keys` is not necessary.
2. To get `name` and `url` you can use destructuring. They aren't passed as the function params.
3. The function passed to `.map` needs to return a value somehow.
4. You can leave out the quotes around `{url}`.

That all comes together as

```
pages.map(({name, url}) => {
  return <li><Link to={url}>{name}</Link></li>
})
```

or

```
pages.map(({name, url}) => 
  <li><Link to={url}>{name}</Link></li>
)
```

Comment: @ZenaMesfin Yes it is best practice to include a key for each item, something unique that is not the index.

Comment: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Answer (score 1):

Good Day , the code for that is this :

```
           pages.map((page,index)=> {
                  <li><Link to={page.url}>{page.name}<Link></li>
           })
```

once you map , the first element would be the name of each variable on the array.

imagine :

```
         foreach (var page in pages)
```

wherein: pages is the list of page ( an array )